# Telerik setting TargetPhysicalFolder dynamically in RadUpload

Tags: asp.net, telerik, radupload

I'm having an issue saving files to physical directories based on a sql query.  I've figured out that i has to do with setting the TargetPhysicalFolder in the aspx, I cannot leave this blank.
Inside of the aspx.cs i tried setting the TargetPhysicalFolder however this does not save the file.

```
RadUpload1.TargetPhysicalFolder = TargetFolderUpload;
```

but if I changed the aspx to be TargetPhysicalFolder = "C:\" it will save the file.  How do I on the front side code change the TargetPhysicalFolder?

```
<telerik:RadUpload ID="RadUpload1" runat="server" TargetPhysicalFolder="?????"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by:

```
foreach( var item in  RadUpload1.UploadedFiles)
{
  item.SaveAs("yourpath");
}
```

Documentation: http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/p_telerik_web_ui_radupload_uploadedfiles.html

Answer (score 0):

If you're basing it on SQL the overall solution would be similar to:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if(some conditional goes here to dictate one folder)
   {
      foreach (Telerik.Web.UI.UploadedFile item in RadUpload1.UploadedFiles)
      {
         item.SaveAs(FirstPathGoesHere);
      }
   }
   else
   {
      foreach (Telerik.Web.UI.UploadedFile item in RadUpload1.UploadedFiles)
      {
         item.SaveAs(SecondPathGoesHere);
      }
}
```

If your application pool is set to anything other than LocalSystem, you may get a error "Access to the path '' is denied." Just a heads up.